# PLSQL Function. To retrieve information for each row of record from Table Y , combine it with Table X and return as string

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

## Currently, I've created a PLSQL Function that is able to display as follows.

```
SELECT Display(R_NAME) FROM REGION WHERE R_REGIONKEY IN (SELECT R_REGIONKEY FROM REGION);
```

Terminal output:

```
0 AFRICA: ALGERIA, ETHIOPIA, KENYA, MOROCCO, MOZAMBIQUE,
1 AMERICA: ARGENTINA, BRAZIL, CANADA, PERU, UNITED STATES,
2 ASIA: INDIA, INDONESIA, JAPAN, CHINA, VIETNAM,
3 EUROPE: FRANCE, GERMANY, ROMANIA, RUSSIA, UNITED KINGDOM,
4 MIDDLE EAST: EGYPT, IRAN, IRAQ, JORDAN, SAUDI ARABIA,
```

================================================================

However, when trying to specifically insert a region name, it will return 5 rows of records instead of 1.

================================================================

```
SELECT Display('ASIA') FROM REGION;
```

Terminal output:

```
2 ASIA: INDIA, INDONESIA, JAPAN, CHINA, VIETNAM,
2 ASIA: INDIA, INDONESIA, JAPAN, CHINA, VIETNAM,
2 ASIA: INDIA, INDONESIA, JAPAN, CHINA, VIETNAM,
2 ASIA: INDIA, INDONESIA, JAPAN, CHINA, VIETNAM,
2 ASIA: INDIA, INDONESIA, JAPAN, CHINA, VIETNAM,
```

================================================================
So far my understanding is that each region E.g. Asia, will have 5 countries, hence the repetition. However, I'm not so sure as to why the for loop will not stop after it has successfully retrieved all the information but it did stop on the previous terminal output.

Answer (score 1):

The `region` table has 5 rows. When you use:

```
SELECT * FROM region
```

It will output all the data for those 5 rows.

When you use:

```sql
SELECT Display('ASIA') FROM REGION;
```

You will call the `display` function passing the literal value `ASIA` for each of those 5 rows; so you will get the same output for each row.

> I'm not so sure as to why the for loop will not stop after it has successfully retrieved all the information but it did stop on the previous terminal output.

It does stop but you are asking it to repeat the action for every row in the table.

If you only want to have a single row then you can filter the table to only have a single row:

```sql
SELECT Display(R_NAME) FROM REGION WHERE R_NAME = 'ASIA';
```

Or you could just use the `DUAL` table that only has one row:

```sql
SELECT Display('ASIA') FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the prompt answer. this is indeed a much better clarification i've gotten thus far in understanding PLSQL, however, if i were to make this function to take in as SELECT Display('ASIA') FROM REGION;, what will be your advice to go about and solve it?

Comment: @xentuous If you only want a single row then the answer is "Don't do it that way". As I said, use a `WHERE` filter to reduce it to a single row (i.e. `SELECT display('ASIA') FROM region WHERE r_name = 'ASIA';`) or use the `DUAL` table which only has a single row.

Comment: alright, thanks for the advice and prompt response once again! i really appreciate it! :)